# How to put a fetch inside a Promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to put a fetch inside a promise, so that I can use it in a Promise.all

```
let dbconnect = new Promise((rs, rj)=> {
  console.log('dbconnect');
  require('mongodb').MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb", { useNewUrlParser: true } )
}),

call =  new Promise((rs, rj) =>{ 
  console.log('fetch');
  fetch(link)})
});



Promise.all( [dbconnect, call] ).then...
```

Both calls get responses, but it doesn't trigger the `Promise.all().then`, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `fetch` already returns a promise, just use it in Promise.all

Comment: That's what i tried first, just realized my problem was with something else... will close this question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return some result in your promises, otherwise, they won't be passed into the chained `.then()`. In your case, if you want to use `Promise` constructors, you should explicitly call `resolve()` with whatever results you want to pass further, like this:

```
let dbconnect = new Promise((rs, rj)=> {
  console.log('dbconnect');
  require('mongodb').MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb", { useNewUrlParser: true }, () => {
    resolve()
  })
}),

call =  new Promise((rs, rj) =>{ 
  console.log('fetch');
  fetch(link).then(resolve)})
});
```

But, as other users already mentioned, you probably don't need to wrap `fetch()` and `MongoClient.connect()` (since v2.0) into `Promise`s as they already return promises. So you can simplify it into:

```
let dbconnect = require('mongodb').MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb", {useNewUrlParser: true}),
call = fetch(link)

Promise.all( [dbconnect, call] ).then...
```

Comment: Connect *also* returns a promise.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Are you sure? https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html#connect says it returns null and you need to pass a callback

Comment: Since 2015, yes: https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/2.2/HISTORY.md#2036-2015-07-07

Comment: Thanks, this was my initial soluton, but it had strange results for me, i'm new to promises pretty much, here is my actual problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53242204/why-am-i-getting-promise-pending-when-using-fetch-in-promise-all