# Why am I getting Promise { <pending> } when using fetch in Promise.all?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

This works fine:

```
....
.then(() => fetch(link, { headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"} }))
  .then( res =>  res.json())
  .then((response)=>{
    console.log(util.inspect(response, {showHidden: true, depth: null, colors: true}));
  })
```

But whenI try to combine the fetch with another promise:

```
let dbconnect = require('mongodb').MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb", { useNewUrlParser: true } ),
    call = fetch(link, { headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"} });


Promise.all( [dbconnect, call] )
  .then( res => [res[0], res[1].json()])
  .then( res => {
    database = res[0];
    sales = res[1];
    console.log(util.inspect(res[1], {showHidden: true, depth: null, colors: true}));
  })
```

I get `Promise { <pending> }` as the output, it seems as though the Promise.all get run before `call()` is completed

Comment: You don't actually *resolve* the promise of the JSON, you just return an array containing it. Why not include unwrapping the JSON in `call`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I see, not sure how to do that though, since I want to include res[0] aswell...

Comment: Make it part of the chain you're passing to all in the first place? Or have the callback on `res[1].json()` pass through `res[0]` too.

Comment: Genious right there!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37555031/why-does-json-return-a-promise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `.then()` on `res[1].json()` because it just returns a promise and you aren't waiting on that promise anywhere.

What I would suggest is that you change to this:

```
let call = fetch(link, { headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"} })
    .then(response => response.json());
```

Then, your `call` variable has already made the `.json()` call and `Promise.all()` will wait on it for you.

---

```
let dbconnect = require('mongodb').MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb", { useNewUrlParser: true } ),
    call = fetch(link, { headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"} })
              .then(response => response.json());

Promise.all( [dbconnect, call] ).then( res => {
    console.log(res[0]);
    console.log(res[1]);
});
```